# dynamic_sidebar() in wordpress not working.....

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to add items through widgets on wordpress, but the "dynamic_sidebar()" code is not working. Here's my code:

```
function templateWidgets(){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Header'),
        'id' => 'headerSidebar'
        ));
}
add_action ('widgets_init', 'templateWidgets')
?>
```

and in my header file:

```
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('headerSidebar')) : ?>
     <?php dynamic_sidebar('headerSidebar');?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

It should be working... the widget registers fine in the admin panel. If I use get_sidebar(), the page will show everything. But if I use dynamic_sidebar the code just gets ignored completely... 
I am using a local copy of wordpress through WAMP.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: try adding `<ul></ul>` tags

Comment: thanks for trying.. didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution! :D
id does not allow camel case (ie: header-sidebar instead of headerSidebar).
I also had the problem of widgets not saving when updated in admin page. 
This solved that problem too. :)